# How to Map Opportunity Owner to Account Owner

Tags: apex, opportunity, account, ownership, account-management

I'm trying to find a way to map the opportunity owner field to the account owner field when a new opportunity is created. So if an opportunity is created by Jon for Account XYZ, which is owned by Jill, then the opportunity owner would be automatically swapped to Jill on creation.

Unfortunately I can't do this with a standard workflow. Any ideas?

Comment: if you are developer, you can do that by trigger for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started :)

```
trigger setOwner on Opportunity (before Insert){

    Set<ID> acctIDs = New Set<ID>();
    Map<ID,ID> accToOwner = New Map<ID,ID>();

    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){

        acctIDs.add(opp.accountID);

    }

    for(Account a : [Select OwnerID From Account Where ID IN :acctIDs])
        accToOwner.put(a.id,a.ownerID);


    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(accToOwner.containsKey(opp.AccountID))
            opp.OwnerID = accToOwner.get(opp.AccountID);
    }


}
```

Comment: Awesome! Got 77% coverage with this (minus the last curly bracket). Thanks so much!

Comment: Good to know. Mark it as the answer if it solves your issue so other with the same issue or use case will know it helped.